# How Can I Connect Using A WebRTC-Offer With PeerJS

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, peerjs

I want to be able to connect using PeerJS but with a WebRTC connection offer. In the docs it is like: `var conn = peer.connect('dest-peer-id');`
https://peerjs.com/docs/#peerconnect

I see that the `peer` object exposes the underlying `RTCPeerConnection`. Is it possible for me to connect peers this way? i am hoping for something like:

```
// on computer-1
let offer = await peer.RTCPeerConnection.createOffer()


// on computer-2
let conn = peer.connect({ offer });
// or
let conn = peer.RTCPeerConnection.connect({ offer });
```

Is there a way i can use the undelying `RTCPeerConnection` to connect to a peer. Im hoping this could be a way to connect without requiring a peer-broker.